# Arranging 8 Letters in a Circle

Tags: probability

A the letters ‘A’, ’B’, ’C’, ’D’, ‘E’, ’F’, ’G’, ’H’ in a circle. ‘A’ and ‘B’ are always next to each other.
The question is to find the probabilities of:

1. Scenario #1: ‘C’ and ‘D’ are next to each other.
2. Scenario #2: ‘A’ and ‘C’ are next to each other.
3. The probability of at least one of the scenarios occur.
4. The probability of both scenarios occur.

I came up with:

1. $P=\frac{3!\cdot 2\cdot 6\cdot 2\cdot 5}{5!\cdot 12}$
2. $P=\frac{4!\cdot 5}{5!\cdot 12}$
3. $P=1-((1-\frac{3!\cdot 2\cdot 6\cdot 2\cdot 5}{5!\cdot 12}) + (1-\frac{4!\cdot 5}{5!12}))$
4. $P=\frac{3!\cdot 4}{5!\cdot 12}$

I'm guessing it’s wrong but I couldn’t came up with something better.

Comment: For #2 the simple answer is $\frac16$, because the $6$ letters C,D,E,F,G,H have equal probability of being on the other side of A.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: if you have $n$ objects that you want to arrange around a circular table, and ignoring rotations, there are $(n-1)!$ possible ways this is possible.

1. Your work is (unfortunately) incorrect. There are $(7-1)!\times 2=1440$ ways to arrange the letters in a circle. (The A and the B counts as one "letter", but you can reverse them, so it must be multiplied by $2$. ) Use the same method to find the number of combinations with C and D next to each other.
2. Since A and B are already next to each other, only one more letter can go beside A. There's a $\frac 16$ probability that it's C.
3. If $P(X)$ is the result from part one and $P(Y)$ is the result from part two, then the probability is 
   $$1-\left(1-P(X)\right)(1-P(Y))$$ 
   In other words, the probability of at least one of them happening is equal to $1$ minus the probability of neither of them happening.
4. Basically the same as part three, if not easier: 
   $$P(X)\times(P(Y)$$